# Can't figure out how to get a flag loop working properly. Keep getting syntax errors.

Tags: python

I need to write a program that will create random math problems.

Each problem should have the following format:

```
    <num> <op> <num>  = ?
```

Where each num represents a random number between -50 and 50 and op is randomly selected from the four basic math operators: +, -, /, *.

The program will present this problem to the user and wait for an answer.  If the answer is correct the program should congratulate the user and exit.  If the answer is not correct the program should allow the user to try again.  The user will be allowed to keep trying until the correct answer is given.

Every time the code is compiled, I get an error at "flag" for syntax but I don't know how to fix it.

```
    def main(): 

        import random
        from operator import add, sub, mul, div

        random.seed()

        ops = (add, sub, mul, div)
        op = random.choice(ops)

        num1 = random.randint(-50,50)
        num2 = random.randint(-50,50)    

        answer = op(num1, num2)

        print("Welcome! Here is your practice problem:\n")

        print(num1, op ,num2,"=?\n")

        guess = int(input("What is your answer?\n")

        flag = True

        while flag:
            guess = int(input("I’m sorry, that is not correct.  Please try again.\n"))

            if guess == answer:
                flag = False
        print("Congratulations! You have answered the problems correctly!\n)


    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a close-paren.

```
int(input("What is your answer?\n")) # < here
```

I would also recommend moving your import statements to outside of the method block.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD regarding missing close-paren.](http://xkcd.com/859/)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed that problem. But now another one has risen.        
Says:

from operator import add, sub, mul, div
ImportError: cannot import name div

How do I make it so I can randomly choose division like the other operators? I searched online and all it says is div.

Comment: Not having that same issue.

Comment: The only thing I changed was an extra ) at the end and added ":" to the end of "while flag" and "if guess == answer" and I'm getting: ImportError: cannot import name div.

Comment: @Drieke: don't change the title each time you advance in this problem, it makes the answers here useless for others.  About the div problem: read the operator docs to see what it offers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the missing paren (mentioned by Makoto), you're also missing a close quote in:

```
print("Congratulations! You have answered the problems correctly!\n")
```

Also, you probably want `break` instead of using a flag, better practice is to place your imports outside of your function declaration, you need to test if `guess == answer` before entering the loop, and you want to print `op.__name__` instead of just op.